# How to proper cleanup child scopes of an Angular directive

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angular-strap, batarang

Background: I am creating a directive based bgDropdown of angularstrap. My goal is to create a similar widget HTML select element, but with custom templates for each element.

The widget works fine. but using Batarang discovered that whenever the user displays the dropdown child scopes are created and are never destroyed. Thus, each time the dropdown is displayed more and more child scopes are created.

I need to understand how to do a proper cleaning of the children scopes.

Sample plunk: http://plnkr.co/edit/xP6HS9?p=preview

```
Step 1: Before first click.
```

[image: Step 1: Pristine]

```
Step 2: After first click and after to closed.
```

[image: After first click]

```
Step 3: After various opens and closes.
```

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe this is actually an issue of `$tooltip` service as I'm able to see the same thing happens in the [dropdown demo](http://mgcrea.github.io/angular-strap/##dropdowns) of AngularStrap itself.

When showing the dropdown, the `$tooltip.show()` will clone the dropdown template and link with the same scope everytime, see [tooltip.js#L198](https://github.com/mgcrea/angular-strap/blob/v2.0.5/src/tooltip/tooltip.js#L198)

```
tipElement = $tooltip.$element = tipLinker(scope, function(clonedElement, scope) {});
```

And in `$tooltip.hide()`, there is no code that destroy scopes created inside the template (e.g. by `ng-repeat`), thus the problem occur.

The easiest workaround that I could imagine, is to specify a `ng-controller` to the `rnDropdown.item.tpl.html` template:

```
<ul tabindex="-1" class="dropdown-menu" role="menu" rn-same-width ng-controller="rnDropdownItemCtrl">
```

then listen to `$destroy` event in controller, to destroy its scope when the dropdown has been removed:

```
.controller('rnDropdownItemCtrl', function ($scope, $element) {
  $element.on('$destroy', function () {
    $scope.$destroy();
  });
})
```

**Example Plunker:** http://plnkr.co/edit/j74pms?p=preview

Comment: useful solution, but a final solution would patch. I'll take the job of linking this post https://github.com/mgcrea/angular-strap/issues/822